# Excel VBA strip string into another cell

Tags: excel, vba

I´m trying to create an Excelsheet that runs multiple VBA scripts after writing anything in A Column.

One part I would like some help with is that the character 2,3 and 4 written in A column (any row) should be written i D column same row.
I also would like to remove any information i D Column if I remove the text from A Column.

[image]

I have manage to create a script that calls modules after writing information i a cell in A Column

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Intersect(Target, Me.Range("A:A")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    Application.EnableEvents = False 'to prevent endless loop
    On Error GoTo Finalize 'to re-enable the events
    Call Modul1.Module
Finalize:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Any help would be much appriciated.

---

This is what I have for now.
It doesn´t work to clear value on all rows only some of them?!

```
Sub Lokation()

Dim n As Long, i As Long, j As Long
n = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
j = 2
For i = 2 To n
    If Cells(i, "A").Value = vbNullString Then

    Cells(j, "D").Value = ("")

    Else

    Cells(j, "D").Value = Mid(Cells(j, "A").Value, 2, 3)

    End If
   j = j + 1
Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: What in particular are you stuck on? Why are you calling another module?

Comment: *character 2,3 and 4 written in A column* Where is it in your example?

Comment: When I´m done with the file it will do much more so I was planning on separate each function do make it easier for me (I have not studied VBA so I google and tries to make it work).
I understand that I need to check the cells in A and if not empty preform the left strip by 4 characters and then remove the first character after that and then place it in D column, same row and loop.
But unfortunatly all I find after trimming using left isn´t adding the trimmed string in another cell.

Character 2,3,4 is 185 in my example it will always be numbers but different number.

Comment: Have a look at the MID formula.

Comment: I don't see any need for VBA. A simple formula like `=Mid(A2, 2, 3)` in the column would do.

Comment: Yes I can use formula but since I am going to do so muck more using VBA I would like to manage to do this using script.
The number of rows that will be used will be different each time and I would like the cells to be empty when not in use.

Comment: Still working on the solution.
I am using MID but in a VBA script although it doesn´t clear the cell in D column when I delete the value on the same row in A Column.
The weird thing is that if I delete some of the cell in A it clear the cell in D but not all rows are working?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wrap this whole piece up in just the `Worksheet_Change` event if you use the following:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Dim columnAcell As Range

    If Intersect(Target, Me.Range("A:A")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

    Application.EnableEvents = False

    For Each columnAcell In Target.Cells
        columnAcell.Offset(0, 3) = Mid(columnAcell, 2, 3)
    Next

    Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

Instead of specifically writing to column D, I've used a cell offset of 3 columns from `Target`. As this code only looks at column A currently, it will always offset to column D.

Things to watch out for though -

- Altering cell(A1) which contains the header would result in cell(D1) being altered. You can prevent this by changing the `Intersect` range from `A:A` to something like `A2:Axxxx`
- Deleting the entirety of column A would result in the loop running for a very long time, not to mention causing column D to move to column C. You may want to prevent users from being able to do this.

Comment: Worked like a sharm! Thanks for the help and the explanation.